# check for duplicate before appendChild

Tags: javascript

```
const pickNewUl = document.getElementById("ullist1");     
var createLi = document.createElement("li");
                            createLi.id = listItems[i].id;
                            createLi.classList.add(pickNewUlsl);
                            createLi.innerHTML = listItems[i].textContent; 
                            createLi.innerHTML += "<a onclick='remove(this)' class='removebtn'>X</a>";
pickNewUl.appendChild(createLi);
```

What I need to check in above code is: I want to check if there are any same id LI exists or not, if not then only it should append, otherwise it will not append.

pickNewUl is a UL list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find for any element inside element with `.querySelectorAll` as below.

```
if (pickNewUl.querySelectorAll('#' + listItems[i].id).length === 0) {
    // Add element    
}
```

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Your complete code should be like below.

```
const pickNewUl = document.getElementById("ullist1"); 
if (pickNewUl.querySelectorAll('#' + listItems[i].id).length === 0) {   
    var createLi = document.createElement("li");
    createLi.id = listItems[i].id;
    createLi.classList.add(pickNewUlsl);
    createLi.innerHTML = listItems[i].textContent; 
    createLi.innerHTML += "<a onclick='remove(this)' class='removebtn'>X</a>";
    pickNewUl.appendChild(createLi);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap you code inside an if:

```js
// the same as before but using pickNewUl instead of document
if (!pickNewUl.getElementById(listItems[i].id)) {
  const createLi = document.createElement("li");
  ...
  pickNewUl.appendChild(createLi);
}
```

Btw, I suggest to use a different approach excluding duplicated `id`:

```js
// The string into querySelector method is a template string.
if (!pickNewUl.querySelector(`[data-item-id="${listItems[i].id}"]`)) {
  const createLi = document.createElement("li");
  createLi.dataset.itemId=listItems[i].id;
  ...
  pickNewUl.appendChild(createLi);
}
```

Comment: But the same ID might be in another UL list

Comment: So I need specifically to check if this exists inside pickNewUl or not

Comment: Generally we should not have duplicated id into the same html page. Btw, I'm going to update my code to work with duplicate id.